# Content Security Policy: The page's settings blocked

Tags: content-security-policy

Hi I am  facing issue related to CSP.

I am getting following error message in my firefox browser.

**Content Security Policy: The page's settings blocked the loading of a resource at http://www.gstatic.com/charts/geomap/3//geomap.swf ("object-src http://localhost:8080").**

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Add `http://localhost:8080` to your `object-src` directive or add `object-src http://localhost:8080` to your policy. (It'd be helpful if you provided your CSP)